# Round table sitting where there are 2 boys between every 2 girls

Tags: combinatorics

We consider seating arrangements around a large round table. Suppose that there are r girls and t boys. How many seating arrangements are there such that for any two girls, there are at least 2 boys sitting between them? Assuming one of the girls always occupies some fixed seat.

---

Here's my attempt:

We know that $2r \leq t$

So arrange $(r-1)$ girls and $2r$ boys in order, then insert the remaining boys, giving 
$$(r-1)!(2r)!\binom{3r+t-2r-1}{t-2r}(t-2r)!$$

simplifying gives

$$(r-1)!(2r)!\binom{r+t-1}{t-2r}(t-2r)!$$

Is this correct? 
What should the answer be if the assumption is removed? (Assuming one of the girls always occupies some fixed seat.)

Comment: Do you distinguish the girls (boys)?

Comment: Yes girls (or boys) are distinguishable @ablmf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the boys and girls are indistinguishable, we have a stars and bars problem.

${t-r-1\choose r-1}$

Now we order the girls and boys

${t-r-1\choose r-1}r!t!$

and since it is a circular table...

${t-r-1\choose r-1}(r-1)!t!$